# Visual studio edit and continue in Xamarin development

Tags: android, mobile, visual-studio-2013, mono, xamarin

When using **Xamarin** platform with Visual Studio 2013 ultimate

Is it possible to use **Visual Studio's edit and continue** feature that lets you modify code and recompile it without having to restart the program from scratch?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

As of January of 2014, Xamarin has no plans to add edit and continue, at least with iOS.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=778

Given how the packages are built and deployed, I'd be surprised to see it (but I've been wrong before).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

It's pretty annoying when i just have to modify a single thing and to test it i have to stop the debug and run it again (sending to the device, etc..). 

Is there a way to get over this issue?

Comment: For starters, using an emulator would probably speed up your development process.