# Does VS2017 support Edit & Continue in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm just starting out with Android development using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367821/visual-studio-edit-and-continue-in-xamarin-development) suggests that E&C isn't possible, but that was a couple of years ago.

Is it still not possible to put a breakpoint somewhere in, for instance, `MainActivity.cs`, and then edit the surrounding code when it hits the break?

I'm using an Android 6.0 emulator created using the Android Virtual Device manager.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not yet available in `Visual Studio 2017` for platforms like `Android` and `iOS` however this works on `UWP` platform.

In [this comment](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=778#c6). Rodrigo Kumpera says:

> We're constantly evaluating what's the best to do for our users. We
>   know how awesome it would be to have Edit and Continue - we really do.

That proves that this feature is not yet available.